# Align a div to the bottom of a sibling div without knowing the sibling div's height

Tags: css, layout, siblings

I want to align a div to the bottom of a sibling div without knowing the height of that sibling div. Here is the layout I'm working with: http://abbymilberg.com/sample-layout.html.

I want to get the right-hand div to align with the bottom of the left-hand div without hard-coding in the top margin, since in my final project the content in the left-hand div will be dynamic and the height will be ever-changing.

I don't know of a way to do this with CSS. I'm guessing there may some way to get an element's height using javascript, but am open to anything that works.

```
<head>

    <style type="text/css">

        #body{text-align:center; margin:0px;}

        #wrapper{border:solid 1px; margin:10px auto 10px; width:800px; 
        padding:10px; text-align:left; }

        #left{margin-right:160px; border:solid 1px;}

        #right{float:right; border:solid 1px; width:150px;}

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="right">
            <h2>Right</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="left">
            <h2>Left</h2>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute and relative positioning:

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wnmq4/)

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that but it was previewing wrong in Dreamweaver... turns out it works in all the browsers though.

Comment: lol, and hence why you never ever trust anything Dreamweaver does other than it's autocomplete in code editing mode.